# PL/SQL Stored Procedure IN Oracle Express - Error

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that takes two parameters, but I received an error. Both parameters are a YEAR, i.e. (2011, 2013). Now I have a table with one field called DATE_DESCRIPTION where I want to insert all the dates between January 1st, 2011 through and up to December 31st, 2013.

Such that when I SELECT DATE_DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE, MY RESULT should look like as an example of one row "Thursday, April 13th, 2012". This should be for all the days between the two parameters.

Eventually I want to add a primary key called DKEY for each day also, but I figured I can start with this and build on it.

Here is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_TABLE (v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

v_START_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

DELETE FROM DATE_DIMENSION;

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('1-JAN-' || v_START_YEAR);
v_END_DATE := TO_DATE('31-DEC-' || v_END_YEAR);

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP

    INSERT INTO DATE_DIMENSION( FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION ),
    VALUES( TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DDth, YYYY') );

    v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
15/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/53    PL/SQL: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
```

Modified Code and Solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_D(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN  INT) AS

v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');

DELETE FROM DATE_D;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP
INSERT INTO DATE_D
(
    DATE_KEY, 
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION

)   
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'),

);

v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't more errors?  You've got a variable `v_current_date` that is never declared.  That should be the first error you get.  I can't imagine that you want to declare two local variables `v_start_date` and `v_end_date` with the same name as the two parameters though that wouldn't create a compilation error, it would just mean that your code almost assuredly won't do what you want.  The lack of a format mask in your `to_date` calls will also likely be problematic.

Comment: Once I run the script I get the "Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors".  Then I type the "show error" command. I am using Oracle XE 11g and from the SQL Plus command line I just add the path @C:\script.sql to run the script.

Comment: You have a spurious comma after the column list in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Post has been updated with a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written the code that compiled with no errors and it does exactly what I wanted. Took the advice of @JustinCave and made the modifications.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_D(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN  INT) AS

v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');

DELETE FROM DATE_DIMENSION;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE 
LOOP
INSERT INTO DATE_DIMENSION
(
DATE_KEY, 
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
)   
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'),

);

v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```